# How can I access ConfigurationSettings using a PHP Cloud Service on Windows Azure?

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-roles

I'd love to be able to access ConfigurationSettings from within a PHP application in a Windows Azure cloud service (web role), but I can't seem to make it work. I've got this configured in my ServiceDefinition.csdef, and I have the corresponding settings configured in my cscfg files:

```
<ConfigurationSettings>
    <Setting name="DBSERVER" />
    <Setting name="DBNAME" />
    <Setting name="DBUSERNAME" />
    <Setting name="DBPASSWORD" />
</ConfigurationSettings>
```

I have tried to do something like `RoleEnvironment::getConfigurationSettings()` using the "new" PHP SDK, but it doesn't seem to work.

I've searched and searched, but can't find any examples or guidance on how to accomplish this. Pointers or ideas? Thanks!