# How do I read configuration data (DB credentials) in a PHP web role in azure?

Tags: php, azure, drupal, azure-web-roles

I want that PHP/Drupal reads configuration settings which are stored in my CSCFG file and in my cloud service instance respectively.

How do I read configuration data (DB credentials) in a PHP web role in azure? I need them to access my database.

I have my DB credentials in two places

- my azure account
- (possibly) in my cscfg file

In my PHP script I want to get this data, so that my CSPKG files don't need to contain credentials. Example:

```
$db_host = azure_getconfig("DbHost"); 
$db_user = azure_getconfig("DbUser"); 
$db_password = azure_getconfig("DbPassword");
```

Is there a standard way how to do this?

**About php_azure.dll:** The approach that is [usually described](http://phpazurecontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=php_azure.dll&referringTitle=Home) did not work for me. The suggested php extension php_azure.dll seems to be abandonded as it is marked as obsolete. I tried to load the extensions in all it's flavors but didn't succeed ("Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\ext\php_azure.dll' - The specified module could not be found.", even though the file exists for sure at the right path.).

So I assume, I shouldn't use php_azure.dll anyway.

There is a similar but unanswered question here:
[How can I access ConfigurationSettings using a PHP Cloud Service on Windows Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14640989/how-can-i-access-configurationsettings-using-a-php-cloud-service-on-windows-azur)

Comment: `“”` quotes are not valid in PHP. Don't use a wordprocessor for editing your code.

Comment: You're right I fixed this. However, it's just a kind of pseudo code based on the examples of php_azure.dll.