# Access Azure Cloud Service ConfigurationSettings in PHP site

Tags: php, azure, drupal

I have a PHP Drupal site deployed as an Azure Cloud Service WebRole. I'd like to read the `ConfigurationSettings` from the `ServiceDefinition` file, in order to get information such as database connection strings, etc.

```
<ConfigurationSettings>
    <Setting name="DBSERVER" />
    <Setting name="DBNAME" />
    <Setting name="DBUSERNAME" />
    <Setting name="DBPASSWORD" />
</ConfigurationSettings>
```

I've read that for Azure Web Sites the appsettings are loaded into Environment Variables, so technically I should be able to use the `getenv()` command to access them. However, the Cloud Service Web Role does not appear to behave this way.

There is also this similar question, but it has gone unanswered:
[How can I access ConfigurationSettings using a PHP Cloud Service on Windows Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14640989/how-can-i-access-configurationsettings-using-a-php-cloud-service-on-windows-azur)

Understanding how to do this is critical in getting my application launch-ready. Any guidance would be greatly appreaciated!

Comment: Did you try to use RoleEnvironmentData?  https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php/blob/master/WindowsAzure/ServiceRuntime/Internal/RoleEnvironmentData.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able do that using Azure PHP SDK found here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php

Like Will mentioned in earlier post, you can use RoleEnvironmentData or  WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.getConfigurationSettings() which should return all your role settings defined in service definition file.

Please give it a try and let us know if you still have issues.

Comment: Marking this as the answer. Unfortunately this code appears to be performing an fread, and in our circumstance, this causes performances issues when the site is under heavy load. To resolve this issue, we've utilized the APC caching extension. When the application is run for the first time, we load all settings into memory for all users. We can then read these values without reading directly from the disc.